# Compiling against libusb-dev on Ubuntu

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, libusb

I am trying to compile the example libusb.c provided by libusb package (if you dl the source code.)

It doesn't work to say the least.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <libusb/libusb.h>
```

That causes it to fail, there is no `libusb/libusb.h` it's `usb.h`, so I change that. And it fails in new and innovative ways.

I've copied the file over, exactly, and named it example.c

I am using these commands and variations:

```
gcc -o example example.c -lusb -L /usr/lib/libusb.a
gcc -o example example.c -lusb -L /usr/lib/libusb.so
```

The errors I get when compiling are:

```
example.c:25: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
example.c: In function ‘main’:
example.c:46: error: ‘libusb_device’ undeclared (first use in this function)
example.c:46: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
example.c:46: error: for each function it appears in.)
example.c:46: error: ‘devs’ undeclared (first use in this function)

Line 25: static void print_devs(libusb_device **devs)

Line 46: libusb_device **devs;
```

At first I followed a tutorial, and that failed to compile, in more or less the same ways, so I decided to just try the provided example, and that failed.

Can anyone help me out? Explain what I am doing wrong, cause I am lost on this one.

Comment: Which file, exactly, did you copy over and name example.c?

Comment: libusb-1.0.8/libusb-1.0.8/examples/lsusb.c

I am about to try compiling it on ubuntu from scratch, as I originally used apt-get install libusb-dev

Comment: Just a note, that what used to be `examples/lsusb.c` which I could get via `apt-get source libusb-1.0-0` in Ubuntu 11.04, is now apparently [examples/listdevs.c](http://git.libusb.org/?p=libusb.git;a=blob;f=examples/listdevs.c;h=6ab891725a36424a7f59d5a8ff2c20a7deaec858;hb=HEAD).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is what I had to do on Debian. It should be at least similar in Ubuntu.

Install `libusb-1.0-0-dev`

Instead of:

```
#include <libusb/libusb.h>
```

do:

```
#include <libusb.h>
```

Compile with:

```
gcc example.c `pkg-config --libs --cflags libusb-1.0`
```

Comment: Super cool, that worked... I don't know what the pkg-config --libs etc stuff even means. Could you explain that or link to some documentation?

Comment: Google it. It's very useful tool. Instead of adding compilation flags manually, you can just specify what libraries you want, pass them to `pkg-config` and it will output all necessary flags.`

Answer (score 7):

Just en explanation why your attempt to replace `libusb/libusb.h` with `usb.h` fails: `usb.h` is a header from `linux-headers`, not from `libusb-dev`. You need `#include <libusb.h>` instead.

Comment: This answer is entirely incorrect.   /usr/include/usb.h is not from linux-headers (which are NOT for userspace to link against), but rather is the include file for the older libusb-0.1 API, while /usr/include/libusb-1.0/libusb.h is the include file for the newer libusb-1.0 API.  They are not directly interchangeable.