# Which system call returns list of devices attached to system in Linux?

Tags: java, c, linux

I am trying to write a C / Java program which will display list of devices attached to system. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

[lsusb](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-how-do-i-list-all-usb-devices/) command will return all the USB devices attached (for Linux kernel 2.3.15 or newer)

there's some advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741141/compiling-against-libusb-dev-on-ubuntu) if you want to call the c function call directly from your code.

Answer (score 0):

In Linux you're probably best off by iterating the `/sys/` hierarchy. There's no such system call, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to list mounted devices on your system. If you are using Linux, Basic read (fopen, fscanf in c, for example) of the file /proc/mounts will tell you the real time mounted devices.

You want to write C or java, so here is an example: 
C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *filename = "/proc/mounts";
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    char line[1000];
    char mountname[1000];
    while(!feof(fp)) {
        fgets(line, 1000, fp);
        sscanf(line, "%s", mountname);
        printf("%s\n", mountname);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any JAVA API available to get list of devices connected to your System?

Comment: @user2201980 Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Java IO.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [**lshw**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw) command.

You can pass through the output of lshw and extract details about devices in the `disk`,  `tape`, `storage` (storage controllers, scsi, sata, sas) and many others class.

Use the `-short` option that gives a compact summary.

Example

```
 sudo lshw -class storage -class disk -class tape -short
```

Output

```
H/W path              Device      Class       Description
==================================================================================
/0/100/4/0                        storage     JMB362 SATA Controller
/0/100/b/0            scsi1       storage     SAS2008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-2 [Falcon]
/0/100/b/0/0.0.0      /dev/sdd    disk        1TB WDC WD10EARS-00Y
```

and here is the list of possible class to pass as parameters of the command:

```
address
bridge
bus
communication
disk
display
generic
input
memory
multimedia
network
power
printer
processor
storage
system
tape
volume
```

as [**lshw**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/lshw) man page reports in Notes

> lshw must be run as super user or it will only report partial information.