# List attached devices on ubuntu in java

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, java-io

I'm a little stumped, currently I am trying to list all of the attached devices on my system in linux through a small java app (similar to gparted) I'm working on, my end goal is to get the path to the device so I can format it in my application and perform other actions such as labels, partitioning, etc.

I currently have the following returning the "system root" which on windows will get the appropriate drive (Ex: "C:/ D:/ ...") but on Linux it returns "/" since that is its technical root. I was hoping to get the path to the device (Ex: "/dev/sda /dev/sdb ...") in an array.

What I'm using now

```
import java.io.File;

class ListAttachedDevices{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File[] paths;

        paths = File.listRoots();

        for(File path:paths) {
            System.out.println(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated, I'm relatively new to SO and I hope this is enough information to cover everything.

Thank you in advance for any help/criticism!

**EDIT:**

Using part of Phillip's suggestion I have updated my code to the following, the only problem I am having now is detecting if the selected file is related to the linux install (not safe to perform actions on) or an attached drive (safe to perform actions on)

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileStore;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileSystemView;

class ListAttachedDevices{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
         ArrayList<File> dev = new ArrayList<File>();

        for (FileStore store : FileSystems.getDefault().getFileStores()) {

            String text = store.toString();
            String match = "(";
            int position = text.indexOf(match);

            if(text.substring(position, position + 5).equals("(/dev")){
                if(text.substring(position, position + 7).equals("(/dev/s")){
                    String drivePath = text.substring( position + 1, text.length() - 1);
                    File drive = new File(drivePath);
                    dev.add(drive);

                    FileSystemView fsv = FileSystemView.getFileSystemView();

                    System.out.println("is (" + drive.getAbsolutePath() + ") root: " + fsv.isFileSystemRoot(drive));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

Disregard previous edit, I did not realize this did not detect drives that are not already formatted

Comment: /dev/sda is not comparable to c: under windows.. Try parsing the output of "mount" maybe

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/18161365/180100

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26650362/4614680

Comment: On linux? Read `/proc/partitions` or run `blockdev --report`

Comment: @rc Hmm that's not a bad idea, although do you think it would make more sense to stay away from parsing that file if possible?

I was hoping to make a interface that in the end looks similar to "sudo blkid -o list"

Comment: @PhilippLudwig That's a great start! Now just to figure out how to check if the /dev/s* path is an attached device or not (I think the fileIO library has a call for this I'm going to look into now)

Comment: Have you had a look at [FileSystemView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/filechooser/FileSystemView.html)?   `isFileSystemRoot(File dir)`looks promising: "Is dir the root of a tree in the file system, such as a drive or partition.".

Comment: @Axel I haven't tried that class/function yet but I will look into it now, I'm curious to see how it plays with the linux file system!

Comment: @Tyler since that's the class that is responsible for getting the devices to display in JFileChooser, I think it should work.

Comment: @Axel I just tried out that function with /dev/sdb1 as the new file and it was returning false, it looks like it behaves the same way as listRoots() it was only returning true for the path of new File("/")

Answer (score 0):

Following [Elliott Frisch's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2970947/elliott-frisch) suggestion to use /proc/partitions I've come up with the following answer. **(Be warned this also lists bootable/system drives)**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

class ListAttachedDevices{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<File> drives = new ArrayList<File>();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/proc/partitions"));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                String text = line;
                String drivePath;

                if(text.contains("sd")){
                    int position = text.indexOf("sd");
                    drivePath = "/dev/" + text.substring(position);
                    File drive = new File(drivePath);
                    drives.add(drive);
                    System.out.println(drive.getAbsolutePath());
                }

                line = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch(IOException e){
            Logger.getLogger(ListAttachedDevices.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
        }
        finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```